# changing google map marker colors

Tags: colors, icons, maps, marker

How do I change the colours of the Icons easily? I just want to be able to change it to a different colour using googles standard markers? Is there a way where I can just declare the color where I create the marker with var = marker..... ?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var map = null;
function initialize() {
var myOptions = {
zoom: 5,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.2361100,-4.5480600),
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
navigationControl: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                            myOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    });

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(50.7184100,-3.5339000); 
  var marker = createMarker(point,'<div style="width:200px"><h2>text</h2><\/div>')


  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(50.9097000,-1.4043500);
  var marker = createMarker(point,'<div style="width:200px"><h2>text</h2><\/div>')

}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{ 
size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
});

function createMarker(latlng, html) {
var contentString = html;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}



</script> 
</head> 
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()"> 
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 535px; height: 500px"></div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472957/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-google-maps-marker - do you need to do anything beyond this?

Comment: Yes. I cant get it to work. I've tried putting code after Var marker = createMarker. ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting Sean's answer from here [How can I change the color of a Google Maps marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472957/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-google-maps-marker).

Try changing your create marker function to

```
function createMarker(latlng, html, iconName) {
var contentString = html;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    icon: iconName,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
});
```

And then call it with

```
var marker = createMarker(point,'<div style="width:200px"><h2>text</h2><\/div>', 'brown_markerA.png')
```

Making sure you place all the icons in the same place as your map page.

You can then adjust how you build up the string for different colors or letters.

Comment: Awesome, please then accept the answer by clicking the big tick above.