# Google maps v3 change marker icon on android webview

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps-api-3, webview

My android application uses webview to render inside it an html page that contains google maps .
the html is located in the assets directory ,  the map works and i can show my location using markers .
i want to be able to change the markers icon , according to the thread [Change marker icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472957/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-google-maps-marker) this is the code of doing so :

```
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151)
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                            mapOptions);

var image = 'images/beachflag.png';
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856);
var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  icon: image
});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

i tried creating a directory inside the assests folder and put my icon in it . 
see [Picture](http://s30.postimg.org/g11kj1gqp/assets.png) .
As you can see i tried once with a directory inside assests , and once the icon is in the same directory as the html . 
and i tried :

```
var image = 'icons/mylocation.png';
var image = 'mylocation.png';
```

both didn't work .
How can i get the javascript to recognize my icon inside android ?
I get the eror :

```
GET file:///android_res/raw/icons/mylocation.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I'm using chrome to debug the javascript code .

Answer (score 0):

You can get drawable image by this link :-

```
file:///android_res/drawable/mylocation.png
```

just write in your html page.

```
var image = 'file:///android_res/drawable/mylocation.png';
```

Comment: Please use some formatting in your post to make it more readable