# Google maps Icon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to set a google maps Icon depending on a integer. I.E. if the variable is 3 it will set the icon to be a brown image marker. I've followed the tutorial found here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple and here
[How can I change the color of a Google Maps marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472957/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-google-maps-marker)

This is my code, my images are located in the same directory but when I load the page I get an error saying Unexpected identifier at icon: image. Whats the problem?

```
function getlocations(){
    var data = <?php echo getjson(); ?>;
    var i = 0;
    var locations = new Array();
    for(i; i < data.length; i++){
        var dataholder = [data[i].misc, parseFloat(data[i].lat), parseFloat(data[i].lng), parseInt(data[i].status)];
        locations.push(dataholder);
    }
    return locations;
}

function createmap() {

    var locations = getlocations();

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.624561, -122.356445),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;
    var markers = new Array();
    var image;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        if (locations[i][3] == 3) {
            image = 'brown_MarkerA.png';
        } else if (locations[i][3] == 4) {
            image = 'brown_MarkerB.png';
        } else {
            image = 'brown_MarkerC.png';
        }

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
            icon: image
        });

        markers.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }

    function AutoCenter() {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
            bounds.extend(marker.position);
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    AutoCenter();
}
```

Comment: Strange. Feels like it should work. Can we see an example of the `locations` array content?

Comment: youre missing a comma `,` after `map: map`

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you very much. Spent an hour looking for that error, kicking myself now.

Comment: No worries. Happens to all of us at some stage.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to Craicerjack who pointed out that I was missing a comma after map: map.