# How to change marker color? Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-markers

```
function createMarker(latlng, item) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
    });
```

This part of the code . On the website it appears as a standard marker, it suits us all but red. How do I change it to another color?

https://yadi.sk/i/ZDONpfoijAjdZ

Answer (score 34):

You should use the [`icon`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Icon) property. For example,

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
});
```

There are many colors available at google.com. Just replace `green-dot` with your color, like:
<sup>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png

http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png

http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png

http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png</sup>

---

## Some examples from Google:

(to get image URL, hover over it or **Right-click → *'Copy Image Location'*** etc)

## <sup>**64×64px**</sup> <sub>[image][image][image][image][image][image]</sub>

## <sup>**32×32px**</sup> <sub>[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]</sub>

## <sup>**12×20px**</sup> <sub>[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]</sub>

More at: https://sites.google.com/site/gmapsdevelopment/ or [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20maps%20markers&tbm=isch&tbs=isz%3Ai) for more.

Comment: And you can find lists of available icons at https://sites.google.com/site/gmapsdevelopment/ and https://gist.github.com/VarunDT/20514fd365a5c27d344a93dada33a690.

Comment: the custom markers seem to force a rect clickable area, so can't add markers close by hand